# Is the following statement about images and preimages true? Give either a proof or a counter-example.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f(f^{-1}(B'))\supseteq B' $.

I really don't have any idea how to do this question so any help would be appreicated.

Comment: (1) What happens if $f$ is a bijection? (2) Can you construct a case where $f^{-1}(B')$ may not be defined?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto x^2$, with $B' = \{ -1 \}$ and see what you discover. Go ahead and tell us about $f^{-1}(B')$ in the comments, and we'll work with you.